# Why is QVariant treating char type as an integer type?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I am trying to write a code snippet which would take a QList of QVariants and would populate the list using ListView.

Use cases with types QString, int, bool, double etc. are successful. However, when I am trying to pass char data type as list elements, it is being treated as integer i.e ASCII value is being taken.

Is there any way to make QVariant treat char as char?

Note: 
I am using Qt5.6.0.
I have tried to probe the type by using QVariant::type() expecting it to return QVariant::Char so that I convert it to string and use it. But, QVariant::type() returned QVariant::Int.

```
int main()
{
    QVariant charVar = 'A';
    qDebug()<< charVar<< "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Actual result:

```
QVariant(int, 65)
```

Expectation:

```
QVariant(char, 'A')
```

Comment: also, just for completeness sake, the actual type of a char-literal  in C is `int` and not `char`. In C++ simple char literals like `'a'` should be `char` but multicharacter-literals like `'abcd'` are still `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char` type of `QVariant` is the same as the type of `int`. If you want to store an actual character, you probably want the type `QChar`.

Notice that `QVariant` only has constructors for `QChar` and `int`. A C++ `char` will be cast to `int` in this case.

To treat your example as a character, you can cast explicitly to `QChar`

```
QVariant v1 = QChar('A');
QVariant v2(QVariant::Type::Char);
v2 = 'B';
qDebug() << v1 << v2;
//Output: QVariant(QChar, 'A') QVariant(int, 66)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response dave. I did not look into the constructors of QVariant. This means, the user will have to pass QChar to the list of QVariant in order to work it as char.

Comment: @VivekVar that depends on your use case I guess. You can also just let the type be `int` and use `toChar()` to convert it back.
`QVariant v3 = 'C'; qDebug() << v3.toChar(); //prints 'C'`